# Does percentile metrics follow the rules of summations?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, quantiles

We are collecting certain metrics using (Graphite + Grafana) use them as a tool to monitor system health and performance.

For one of the latency metric, we get the total time as well as the latencies for all the sub-components it is composed of.

We display 99th percentile for all the values. However, if we sum up the 99th percentiles for latencies of sub-components, they do not equate to the 99th percentile of the total time.

Essentially it comes down if the percentiles can follow summation rules. i.e.

```
if 
a + b + c + d = s

then,
p99(a) + p99(b) + p99(c) + p99(d) = p99(s) ?
```

Will this hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it does not happen. I will show an example for the median

> median(1:5)
>   [1] 3
>   median(c(17,2,1,1,1))
>   [1] 1
>   median(c(18,4,4,5,6))
>   [1] 5

And obviously 5 does not equal 1 + 3.

The same can happen for any quantile of course but generating an example for the 99th centile would take up more space.

Comment: To add to this, in my case, they were not at the exact same time. So yeah it makes sense now.

Comment: @mdewey I agree with your conclusion but don't understand your example.  If by median(1:5) you mean  that the data is 1 2 3 4 5 then I agree the sample median is 3. But what does c(17,2,1,1,1) mean?

Comment: @MichaelChernick it is a vector containing those five elements in that order